# Finding selector for table row class for selenium crawler

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make an crawler/auto clicker on python where my target is to click all row header in a table to expand them and show the nested rows. I cannot seem to find the correct selector to use, I tried to use driver.find_elements_id, driver.find_elements_xpath, but it isnt working.

here is what i am using

```
PATH = "C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://int.soccerway.com/")
link = driver.find_elements_id("tr")
link.click()
```

and here is a snippet of the website

```html
<tr class="group-head  clickable " id="date_matches-1886" stage-value="14">
            <th colspan="4"><h3><span class="flag_16 left_16 australia_16_left">Australia - Queensland NPL Youth League</span></h3></th>
            <th class="competition-link"> <a href="/national/australia/queensland-npl-youth-league/2021/regular-season/r62203/"><span>More…</span></a></th>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be `date_matches-1886` instead of `tr` in your example. You may be instrested in the function called `find_element_by_tag_name`. But I think it is better to use `find_element_by_class_name('clickable')` in your case. Have a look at [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for more.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://int.soccerway.com/')
link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('clickable')
link[0].click()
link[2].click()
```

Comment: this helped a lot.i was trying the class name group-head clickable but i didnt try just clickable. it's working now.